# Is Organa in "Dark Resurrection" fan movie the original princess Leia?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, fan-fiction

I have recently watched ["Dark Resurrection - volume 1"](http://www.darkresurrection.com/it/episodi/volume1.html), an independent fan movie set in the Star Wars universe. In the movie, there is a old Jedi master named *Organa* and - [according to IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1105757/) - she should be a direct reference to the original princess Leia Organa from Lucas's movies.

Since IMDB is not always a completely reliable source - and I have not found anything in the main site, is there any evidence that it is exactly the same character as the original trilogy?

I am talking about press releases or interviews from actors/producers, etc.

I hope this question is not off-topic, being on a non-canonic Star Wars fan-movie. If so, just let me know :)

Comment: I don't know the answer but this is definitely on-topic, just so you know :)

Comment: Considering "volume 1" is in the title could it be possible for it to be revealed later on?

Comment: @IanAuld Honestly, I don't think so - basically, because the "volume 1" subtitle has been added after some times, the original title being "Dark Resurrection". Anyway, since they still have to film the sequel, I cannot say for sure :D